# How to draw a line from one Point in an ArrayList to the other closest other Point in the ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, line, draw

This is my Lab class which contains a method called findNearest() which takes a single Point object as a parameter and an ArrayList of Points as a parameter and returns the nearest Point in the list to the single Point. 
In my main method I created an ArrayList of 10 random Point objects. drawn on Points on the StdDraw canvas.

I want to connect the points closest to another point in the ArrayList but I don't know how...can anyone help me out?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Lab {
    public static void main(String[] args){

        //Create 10 random points and put them in a List
        ArrayList<Point> thePoints = new ArrayList<Point>();
        for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
            Point p = new Point(600 * Math.random(), 600 * Math.random());
            thePoints.add(p);
        }
        StdDraw.setCanvasSize(600,600);
        StdDraw.setXscale(0.0 , 600.0);
        StdDraw.setYscale(0.0 , 600.0);

        //Draw the points in the List
        for( Point p : thePoints){
            p.draw();
        }

        //Draw lines to the nearestNeighbors

        StdDraw.show();

    }
    public static Point findNearest(Point aPoint, ArrayList<Point> theList){
             double minimumDistSoFar = Double.MAX_VALUE;
                Point nearest = null;

                for (Point p : theList) {
                    if (p.getMyX() == minimumDistSoFar && p.getMyY() == minimumDistSoFar) {
                    }

                    double pDistance = distance(p);
                    if (pDistance < minimumDistSoFar) {
                        minimumDistSoFar = pDistance;
                        nearest = p;
                   }
                }

            return nearest; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

StdDraw has a line() method.  Here's a link to the documentation: [Documentation](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/stdlib/javadoc/StdDraw.html)

This method takes four doubles, x and y of the start of the line, and x and y of the end of the line.  You could draw a line beginning at one of the Point's x and y, and then set the x and y of the end of the line to the nearest Point's x and y.

I imagine you could do something like this:

```
for(Point p : thePoints)
{
    Point p2 = findNearest(p, thePoints);
    StdDraw.line(p.getX(), p.getY(), p2.getX(), p2.getY());
}
```

From my understanding this should draw a line from the point in the loop to the nearest point.